# angular js1 basic application using http-server doesn't enter the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.5

Below is the index.html file:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title> My Contacts App </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"></link>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My contact App </h1>
  <div controller="contactCtrl as ctrl">
    {{ ctrl.nm }}

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js is as shown below:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("contactCtrl",createContacts);

function createContacts()
{
  this.nm = "Hey";

console.log("INside controller");
}
```

Problem: When I start http-server from the same directory where the source files are and type http://127.0.0.1:8080 the browser just displays static html content. It neighter displays the value of the variable "nm" nor shows anything from console.log
I am at a beginner level. 
TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be `ng-controller`:

```
 <div ng-controller="contactCtrl as ctrl">
   {{ ctrl.nm }}
 </div>
```

Here is an example on how to use the `ng-controller` directive in the html:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("contactCtrl",createContacts);

function createContacts()
{
  this.nm = "Hey";

console.log("INside controller");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title> My Contacts App </title>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"></link>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My contact App </h1>
  <div ng-controller="contactCtrl as ctrl">
    {{ ctrl.nm }}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by pritam is correct. Why not go traditional way.

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("contactCtrl",function($scope){
        $scope.nm = "Hey";
        console.log("Inside controller");
    });
```

and in the template just use {{ nm }}

Comment: It is advisable to use `controller as` syntax symbol and that is what the angularjs developers endorse.

Comment: Tried that way too but still nothing is displayed in console as well as browser.